# WCF Service hangs only when returning data from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wcf

I have a WCF server with the following services:

```
public Foo[] GetFoo()
{
    return _entities.Fooes.toArray();
}
```

and

```
public String[] GetString()
{
    String[] s = new String[100];
    /*...*/
    return s;
}
```

The Foo class is defined by the EF (EF 5.0, T4). In the client, if I call the `GetString()` service, everything goes well, but if I call the `GetFoo()` service, it hangs till `TimeoutException`. Why does it hang?

Comment: How many Fooes do you have in DB?

Comment: Exactly 6. However it contains a foreign key, but that table is small too.

Comment: Dont return the Array immediatly store it into a variable, debug the Code and have a look at the variable is it like you expect?

Comment: Yes, every Foo has two properties: a `String` and a `System.Collections.Generic.HashSet'1[FooProject.Service.FooBar]` because of the foreign key.

Comment: Is lazy loading deactivated?

Comment: Lazy loading is active.

Comment: Daniel you should learn about the @ Symbol and what its for on SO, me and @codework do not get notified when you don't write this. Try deactivating lazy loading and proxy generation.